# background-color aleatorio na div sem que a mesma cor se repita duas vezes consecutivas

Tags: php, css

Bom quero criar uma sequencia de `DIV`, só que eu quero que cada `DIV` tenha em seu `background-color` uma cor aleatória previamente estalecida, tipo preto, amarelo e verde, porem não quero que essas cores se repitam uma após a outra.

Tipo :: amarelo >> amarelo >> preto  >> verde >> preto

Quero que fique algo tipo assim :: amarelo >> preto >> amarelo >> verde >> preto

Atualmente uso esse código pra gerar as cores aleatórias pro `background-color`, porém esse código repete as cores uma após a outra, já que a cor aleatória é gerado no refresh da página.

```
<?php
$cor = array();
$cor[1] = "#CFF";
$cor[2] = "#9FF";
$cor[3] = "#600";
$cor[4] = "#FF0";
$cor[5] = "#C69";
$cor[6] = "#0F0";
$contador = count($cor);
$aleatorio = rand(1,$contador);
?>

<style>
div{margin-left:15px; width:100px; height:100px; float:left}
</style>

<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[$aleatorio] ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[$aleatorio] ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[$aleatorio] ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[$aleatorio] ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[$aleatorio] ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[$aleatorio] ?>"></div>
```

No caso o meu problema não é repetir as cores, e sim repetir a mesma cor uma após a outra. Por isso citei o padrão acima " amarelo >> amarelo >> preto >> verde >> preto", nesse caso cores iguais se repetem uma apos a outro. As cores até podem repetir INÚMERAS vezes, porém não quero que ela se repita uma apos a outra, quero que fique algo do tipo :: Amarelo >> preto >> Amarelo >> preto

Comment: não entendi o problema, é repetir as cores no mesmo load (cada div deve ficar com uma cor diferente) ou em loads diferentes (todos os divs da mesma cor, mas mudando a cada refresh)?

Comment: @luigibertaco o problema não é repetir as cores, e sim repetir a mesma cor uma após a outra. Por isso citei aquele padrão no exemplo " amarelo >> amarelo >> preto >> verde >> preto". No caso as cores podem repetir INÚMERAS vezes, porém nao quero que ela se repita uma apos a outra, tipo :: Amarelo >> amarelo >> preto >> preto

Comment: então a resposta do @Bacco resolve teu problema.

Comment: @ivanveloso se tiver a curiosidade de ver, dei uma bela otimizada no código. A lógica é a mesma, mas deixei mais limpo e objetivo. Jajá deleto esse comment aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você quer alternar as cores entre as `div`s, é mais fácil criar uma função:

```
<?php
   function corAleatoria() {
      static $corAnterior = 0;
      static $cor = array( '#CFF', '#9FF', '#600', '#FF0', '#C69', '#0F0' );

      $aleatorio = rand( $corAnterior?1:0, count( $cor ) - 1 );
      if( $aleatorio >= $corAnterior ) $aleatorio++;
      $corAnterior = $aleatorio;
      return $cor[$aleatorio - 1];
   }
?>

<style>
   div{margin-left:15px; width:100px; height:100px; float:left}
</style>

<div style="background-color: <?php echo corAleatoria(); ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color: <?php echo corAleatoria(); ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color: <?php echo corAleatoria(); ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color: <?php echo corAleatoria(); ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color: <?php echo corAleatoria(); ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color: <?php echo corAleatoria(); ?>"></div>
```

Assim, a cada vez que for chamada a `corAleatoria()`, será retornada uma string com a cor sorteada e não repetida.

Se futuramente for gerar as `div`s em *loop*, pode simplificar o processo desta maneira:

```
<style>
   div{margin-left:15px; width:100px; height:100px; float:left}
</style>

<?php
   $corAnterior = 0;
   $cor = array( '#CFF', '#9FF', '#600', '#FF0', '#C69', '#0F0' );
   $max = count( $cor ) - 1;

   for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
      $aleatorio = rand( $corAnterior?1:0, $max );
      if( $aleatorio >= $corAnterior ) $aleatorio++;
      $corAnterior = $aleatorio;

      echo '<div style="background-color: '.$cor[$aleatorio - 1].'"></div>';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegue resolver de uma forma mais simples:

```
<?php
$cor = array();
$cor[1] = "#CFF";
$cor[2] = "#9FF";
$cor[3] = "#600";
$cor[4] = "#FF0";
$cor[5] = "#C69";
$cor[6] = "#0F0";

//altera de forma aleatória os membros da array.
shuffle($cor);
?>

<style>
div{margin-left:15px; width:100px; height:100px; float:left}
</style>

<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[0] ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[1] ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[2] ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[3] ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[4] ?>"></div>
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $cor[5] ?>"></div>
```

Comment: O unico problema que eu vejo com essa solução é que se aumentar o número de `div`s tem que aumentar o número de cores. Mas se o numero de divs for igual, é uma solução boa.

Comment: em primeira instancia não tinha percebido esse fator ao qual o @Bacco se referiu. Seu código é mais simples, isso é, porém é limitado, e como o Bacco disse, conforme aumentar o numero de div's também terei que aumentar o numero de cores, o que o torna inviável em alguns casos. De qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Se a sua ideia é ter um numero indeterminado de div, deveria então as criar dinamicamente através de uma função que aceitasse como parâmetro o numero de divs que quer criar. Não vejo qualquer sentido em tantas chamadas de funções.